# Is there a way to impose integer constraint in when using Variable() in R

Tags: r

Trying to solve an optimization problem in R with Variable() and Problem() I have encountered some difficulties with imposing the integer condition for the variables.

I know when using Variable() it is not very intuitive and, for example, if you want to have "x" dividing, you need to use inv_pos(x) instead of 1/x (which gives an error). So I am guessing there is a workaround to this but I am unable to find it.

```
p <- Variable(100)

objective <- Minimize(sum(p))

constraints <- list(p%%1==0) #this is what I expected to work
constraints <- list((p-1*floor(p))==0) #this is what I expected to work too

problem <- Problem(objective, constraints)

sol <- solve(problem, solver="ECOS") #the problem might not be optimzable 
                                      with ECOS but I have not reached to 
                                      that point
```

Is there any way to impose this "integer" condition?

Comment: I'm assuming this is the `CVXR` package (based on your previous questions), please keep each question self-contained/complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int` is available to define integer variables:

```
library(CVXR)

p <- Int(100)
```